# npm install "Failed at the ref@0.1.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'"

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner, node-gyp

Maybe a long shot, but here goes. I'm attempting to install a package via NPM (karma iOS launcher) and am getting the above error (`Failed at the ref@0.1.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'`)

I'm running:

OS X 10.10.4, 
Node 0.12.7 (also tried with 0.10), 
NPM 2.12.1, 
xcode 6.4. I thought it may have been a compatibility with my node version (karma ios launcher is a pretty old package) so tried downgrading to a version recent to the package but no avail.

A newbie to npm, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks. Full error logs here: https://github.com/xdissent/karma-ios-launcher/issues/4#issuecomment-129241003

Comment: It won't work on 0.12, but I can get `karma-ios-launcher` installed on v0.10.39 without issues.

Comment: @robertklep I downgraded to 0.10.40 and managed to get it installed (not sure why this didn't work before). I've hit another wall now but a step in the right direction I guess. Thanks